# App remains open after clicking exit? what is wrong?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-apps

today I updated a google play services lib into an app for a newer version. Eclipse is not giving me any kind of errors, I compiled it and when I test on my phone works fine then I go to the menu and select exit and confirm with a yes to close it and the app disappears from screen.
But when you hit the square at the bottom of the phone (when you list all opened apps) the app is still there running! o_O

Prior to the update the app was closing fine and now remains active after exit. But I dont think that gps could cause this kind of issue. Any suggestion???

Here is my MainActivity.java (where the exit menu process is executed)

```
package com.myapp.radio;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.myapp.radio.R;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

private Intent bindIntent;
private RadioService radioService;

private static boolean isExitMenuClicked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    isExitMenuClicked = false;

    // Bind to the service
    bindIntent = new Intent(this, RadioService.class);
    bindService(bindIntent, radioConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isExitMenuClicked == true)
        finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    if (radioService.getTotalStationNumber() <= 1) {
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent i;

    final String thisClassName = this.getClass().getName();
    final String thisPackageName = this.getPackageName();

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.radio) {
        if (!thisClassName.equals(thisPackageName + ".MainActivity")) {
            i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.exit) {
        String title = "Cerrar aplicación";
        String message = "¿Realmente desea salir?";
        String buttonYesString = "Si";
        String buttonNoString = "No";

        isExitMenuClicked = true;

        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle(title);
        ad.setMessage(message);
        ad.setCancelable(true);
        ad.setPositiveButton(buttonYesString,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        if (radioService != null) {
                            radioService.exitNotification();
                            radioService.stop();
                            radioService.stopService(bindIntent);
                            isExitMenuClicked = true;
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });

        ad.setNegativeButton(buttonNoString, null);

        ad.show();

        return true;

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.about) {
        if (!thisClassName.equals(thisPackageName + ".AboutActivity")) {
            i = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.facebook) {
        if (!thisClassName.equals(thisPackageName + ".FacebookActivity")) {
            i = new Intent(this, FacebookActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.twitter) {
        if (!thisClassName.equals(thisPackageName + ".TwitterActivity")) {
            i = new Intent(this, TwitterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// Handles the connection between the service and activity
private final ServiceConnection radioConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        radioService = ((RadioService.RadioBinder) service).getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        radioService = null;
    }
};

protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: This is normal behavior for Android.  The OS may choose to keep apps in memory after you close them.  Different devices and different Android versions may exhibit different behaviors in this respect.

Comment: typo, when I meant MainActivity actually is BaseActivity.java

Comment: @ScottKronheim is there a way to get rid of it and force closing? The only way you can close the app from the users phone is to view the running processes and force detention or pressing the square and click on the X on the uppers right corner in the app.

Comment: There is no way to force the behavior that you want.  Android does not work that way.

Comment: @ScottKronheim actually I tested two apps just a moment ago.. an old one published my me and an app from other user at playstore. Both remains open after hiting exit, honestly is the first time that I see this. My doubt is that my app has intersticial ads, and if it remains open in the background even after hiting exit, from time to time an ad pop ups in the  user phone while is doing other tasks. The intersticial ad of the app running in background.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not related to Google Play Services, this is how Android works.

When you leave any application it's still alive for some time. There are no any running Activities, but Application instance is active. And if you launch it again after short time - it's started pretty quick, because some application data inherited from previous run. For example, all the static variables - they are still alive and contains previous values. It can cause very complex bugs at the restarted application, so be aware of that!

That extra living time depends on current conditions. If there are enough memory - it's longer, not enough - killed sooner.

Comment: thanks Sergey for the explanation! The ad poping out while is in "alive mode" after exiting, could be solved in any way? cause the apps thinks its running and launchs the interstitial from background. o_O

Comment: @unarea, as I wrote before, there are no any alive Activities, but some background works can be in progress. So if you do not want them to show any new UI, you should explicitly stop all the working tasks before exit. The stopping method can vary and depends on your actual processing: Thread, AsyncTask, Handler, Service, ... It's not clear from your question who is running the post mortem popup.

Comment: Usually, ad networks (e.g. AdMob) forbid showing interstitial ads at random moments. It's direct way to be banned by the network! So according to the common rules, the ad should be shown as a reaction to some user action (e.g. pressing some button). Maybe you need to revise your app behavior related to advertisement...